# Python cookiecutter loop over list

Tags: bash, python-2.7, jinja2, cookiecutter

I am trying to loop over all items in a Python cookiecutter json list and run a bash command based on each item.

**Setup**

I have the following `cookiecutter.json`:

```
{
    "directory_name": "df-sharp",
    "servers": ["db", "web"],
    "myweb_provisioner": "webck"
}
```

I have `{{cookiecutter.myweb_provisioner}}.sh`, which contains this `jinja2` code:

```
{% for server in cookiecutter.servers %}
mkdir -p ~/myproj/host_types/{{ server }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Problem**

When I run `cookiecutter create-server-tree`, I get the following:

```
Select servers:
1 - db
2 - web
Choose from 1, 2 [1]: 2
```

and the contents in `webck.sh` are:

```
mkdir -p ~/myproj/host_types/w
mkdir -p ~/myproj/host_types/e
mkdir -p ~/myproj/host_types/b
```

The `Select` menu should not appear. I do not want to choose between the 2 elements in the list. I want to loop over them and construct 2 bash commands - one command per element. I am trying to loop over the list like shown [here](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/dict_variables.html#basic-usage) or [here](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter/issues/479#issue-97892967).

**What I want**

This is what I want: `cookiecutter create-server-tree` should produce `webck.sh` which contains the following:

```
mkdir -p ~/myproj/host_types/db
mkdir -p ~/myproj/host_types/web
```

How can I iterate over the `servers` list and use each of the list elements (instead of one character at a time)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I was using the wrong terminology. If the value in a key-value pair is a plain list, then cookiecutter calls that value (list) as providing "[Multiple Choice options](http://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/choice_variables.html#basic-usage)". So if I put in a plain list as the value for the key "servers", then I should expect to get the list of choices that I got above:

```
Select servers:
1 - db
2 - web
Choose from 1, 2 [1]: 2
```

What I needed was a nested dictionary as the value for the key servers, like they show [here](http://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/dict_variables.html#dictionary-variables-1-5) - it is called Dictionary Variables. To use this to answer my question, I changed my `cookiecutter.json` file to this:

```
{
    "directory_name": "df-sharp",
    "servers": {"server_list": ["db", "web"],
                "server_ips: ["123", "456"]"
               },
    "myweb_provisioner": "webck"
}
```

and then I used jinja2 as shown below:

```
{% for server in cookiecutter.servers.server_list %}
mkdir -p ~/myproj/host_types/{{ server }}
{% endfor %}
```

and this gave me what I wanted.

However, I had to use `cookiecutter create-server-tree --no-input`([link](http://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/cli_options.html#cmdoption-no-input)). This is because I have **not** been able to suppress only the prompt for a dictionary variable. I would have wanted this:

```
directory_name[df-sharp]: 
myweb_provisioner[webck]:
```

and some way of specifying the key `servers` as a default argument. Actually, they have a default option [here](http://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/suppressing_prompts.html#advanced-example-defaults-extra-context). It would be something like this and requires using [their API](http://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#api-reference):

```
cookiecutter('create-server-tree/',
             no_input=True,
             extra_context={"servers": {"server_list":['db','web'],
                                        "server_ips": ["123", "456"]
                                       }
                           }
            )
```

However, how should a user incorporate this `extra_content={...}` argument into an actual cookiecutter project and refer to "server_list" in `jinja2` templated script? I don't know.

Comment: you can suppress prompts for specific options by making nested cookiecutters - the outer one which should be directly used by your user would render the cookiecutter.json with the extra context, the inner one would then be called with these rendered optioins and --no-input by the outer one's post gen hook https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/hooks.html (although this is kinda ugly, but the cookiecutter is neither very flexible nor sophisticated at this point)

Comment: It would be quite unwieldly but that's an interesting idea. It would have the advantage that the [extra context](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/suppressing_prompts.html#advanced-example-defaults-extra-context) would not be required. Thanks!